# How do I use a .CAP file to update BIOS driver

Tags: drivers, motherboard, bios

I just built a new PC and am in the process of installing the latest drivers from my motherboard manufacturer's homepage [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X470-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download/) (I have an ASUS ROG STRIX X470-F Gaming motherboard). There is a driver for the BIOS (first in the list) which I would like to install. However, when I download the ZIP file, all it contains is a single .CAP file and I don't know what it is nor what to do with it.

My question:

How do I use this .CAP file to update the BIOS driver?

Comment: Download your Bios Manual and read it...https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X470-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_Manual/

Comment: Update bios manual After you get all other drivers and software installed.

Comment: It seems like a good place to start :). Thank you.